# Proof by induction on coin problem

Tags: induction

Suppose I have an unlimited supply of $k$th and $(k+1)$th cents where $k \in \mathbb{N}$, then I can always pay integer bills starting from $k(k-1)$ cents using only the two types of coins I have. Let this statement be $P(k)$. So, 
$P(1):$ I have coins of $1$ and $2$ cents, then I can pay any bill starting from $1(1-1)=0$ cents. (This is true because it does not require any coins).
$P(2):$ I have coins of $2$ and $3$ cents, then I can pay any bill starting from $2(2-1)=2$ cents.
$P(5):$ I have coins of $5$ and $6$ cents, then I can pay any bill starting from $5(5-1)=20$ cents.
Now $P(k)$ seems to hold fine for some arbitrarily chosen positive integer, but I would like to validate this statement using the principle of induction:
**Base case:**
$P(1)$ holds. (See from above)
**Induction on $k$:**
Assume $P(i)$ holds for $1\leq i \leq k$. Using this assumption I have to prove $P(k+1)$ holds. I am stuck here, how should I approach it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to use induction? Even with strong induction, I don't think you'll have an easy time using $P(i)$'s to prove $P(k+1)$.

Comment: @A.J. Are there any other ways to prove it?

Comment: Perhaps fix $k$ first, then use (strong) induction on the amount on the bill $n \ge k(k-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an outline of an induction proof  for a fixed $k$ :

$k(k-1)$ cents can be paid with $(k-1)$  **k**-cent coins.

$k(k-1) +1$ cents can be paid with $(k-2)$  **k**¢ coins plus $1$ **k+1** cent coin.

$k(k-1) +2$ cents can be paid with $(k-3)$  **k**¢ coins plus $2$ **k+1** cent coins.

$$\vdots$$

$k(k-1) + k-2$ cents can be paid with $1$  **k**¢ coin plus $(k-2)$ **k+1**¢ coins.

$k(k-1) + k-1$ cents can be paid with $(k-1)$ **k+1** cents coins.

i.e. $(k^2-1)$ cents can be paid with $(k-1)$  **k+1**-cent coins.

But then $k^2$ cents can be paid with $k$ **k**-cent coins, and from there the cycle repeats.